# How to remove an "mouseup" event listener in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

Here i am drag an element and droping in another place it works well if i don't use event listeners but if i use it in this format it is not performing "place" operation.

this link contains my code "with Event Listeners"
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/vishwateja2000/wHprQ/2/

this link contains my code "without Event Listeners"
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/vishwateja2000/W2Pgq/1/

```
document.getElementById("div2").addEventListener("mousedown", down);

function down(){
    t=1;
    document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mouseup", place);

    document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mousemove",function() {
        myFunction(event);
    });
}

function place(){ 
    document.getElementById("div1").removeEventListener("mousemove",function() {
         myFunction(event);
    });
}
function placeobj(x,y,x1,y1,l,r){
    var cpx = parseInt(x);
    var cpy = parseInt(y);
    var amtx=parseInt(x1);
    var amty=parseInt(y1);
    var of=10;
    document.getElementById("div2").style.left=cpx-amtx+l+"px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.top=cpy-amty+r+"px";
}
function myFunction(e) {
    if(t==1){
        x1 = e.clientX;
        y1 = e.clientY;
        var el=document.getElementById('div2');
        l=el.offsetLeft;
        r=el.offsetTop;
        t=10;
    }
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    placeobj(x,y,x1,y1,l,r);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used different functions when adding and removing the `mousemove` event.
Although they have the same functionality they are different functions in memory and so are treated differently.

Take a look at the fixed version:
http://jsfiddle.net/PN3TA/

The `removeEventListener()` has to have the same event name + function as used in the `addEventListener()` to remove the right event. The function can't be an anonymous function as that creates a new function (although it might look the same). You need to use a reference (like a pointer) which can be a named function or a variable.

**NOTE:**  Also when passing a function to these methods you don't have to wrapped in an anonymous function if the original function expects to get the same arguments as the anonymous function. I mean, this:

```
 document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mousemove",function() {
    myFunction(event);
});
```

Could be written like this, because `myFunction()` expects an `event` argument which will be supplied anyway, saving you a function wrapper:

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mousemove",  myFunction);
```

Comment: @JVT if you think this answer was helpful, you can also upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've to attach an event with a reference to a function, then you can use the same reference to remove the listener. You can't remove anonymous event handlers with [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener).

Attach with a reference:

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

Remove with a reference:

```
document.getElementById("div1").removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

Notice, that `e` is automatically passed to handler, you don't need to pass it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use embedded event functions. Have named event functions. For example:

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("mouseup", myFunction);

myFunction(event){
if(t==1){
        x1 = e.clientX;
        y1 = e.clientY;
        var el=document.getElementById('div2');
        l=el.offsetLeft;
        r=el.offsetTop;
        t=10;
    }
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    placeobj(x,y,x1,y1,l,r);
}
```

Now you can easily remove the event like this:

```
document.getElementById("div1").removeEventListener("mouseup", myFunction);
```

Also I would recommend using jQuery instead :)