# Javascript class name manipulation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two css selectors linked up to an html element. Onmousedown javascript is supposed to change the class to 'closeMenuButtonActive' and onmouseup it should wait 500ms and then change the class name to 'closeMenuButtonNotActive'. ***For some reason this code isn't working correctly!*** I tried doing `alert(this.className);` to see what was going on, the alert said the correct closeMenuButtonNotActive. The strange part is that ***I looked at the element in the inspector and the class name hadn't changed!*** Here is my inline javascript code:

```
<div id="closeMenuButton" class="closeMenuButtonNotActive" onmousedown="this.className = 'closeMenuButtonActive';" onmouseup="window.setTimeout(function(){this.className = 'closeMenuButtonNotActive';},500);">
```

Comment: You should look at this answer on how to change an element's class name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/509710

Comment: I've already seen it. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: `this` is in the context of that Anonymous function. I would keep JavaScript separate from HTML, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call you function with "bind" to keep the scope of "this".

```
window.setTimeout(
function(){
    this.className = 'closeMenuButtonNotActive';
}.bind(this),
500);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because `this` is refering to `window` on this function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  // Wrong this
  this.className = 'closeMenuButtonNotActive';
},500);
```

Instead you could do

```
 var elem = this;
 window.setTimeout(function() {
  elem.className = 'closeMenuButtonNotActive';
},500);
```

Of if you don't want to pollute the global scope:

```
(function(elem) {
   window.setTimeout(function() {
    elem.className = 'closeMenuButtonNotActive';
  },500);
)(this);
```

Anyway, to prevent further problems that are hard to debug, you should really consider at least using a function in the HTML `<div onmouseup="doStuff(this)">` and define doStuff from the javascript code. Or even better, add the mouse events listeners directive [from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053359/how-to-remove-an-mouseup-event-listener-in-java-script).